# Adding a clause

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel formula that currently looks up a user ID in another worksheet and if it finds it then it pulls information from a cell 6 places away.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A,'ARM Requests'!A:F,6,FALSE),"")
```

However in a sitiuation where the cell is blank I want to make an additional check to see if column P on the same worksheet has a value **Virtual** and if it does then I want to populate the field with the value **Migrated**?

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A,'ARM Requests'!A:F,6,FALSE),IF(AND(A:A="",P:P="Virtual"),"Migrated",""))
```

However much faster is to use something like this, say in `B1`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,'ARM Requests'!A:F,6,FALSE),IF(AND(A1="",P1="Virtual"),"Migrated",""))
```

and then drag formula down.

Comment: I'm getting a circular reference warning for both of them - is this something I should ignore?

Comment: where do you put your formula? in column A or P? If yes, you can't do it. Put formula in any other column

Comment: It works now thanks - if I wanted to add multiple clauses for column P (e.g. OR Physical OR Soft) how would I do it?

Comment: change `AND(A1="",P1="Virtual")` to `AND(A1="", OR(P1={"Virtual","another value","something else"}))` or `AND(A1="", OR(P1="Virtual",P1="another value",P1="something else"))`